# Segmentation Fault in reading a file in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to read a file which has each line containing two integers delimited by tabs into an array of edges.

This is my definition of an edge.

```
typedef struct Edge{
    int first;
    int second;
}Edge;
```

This is my code.

```
const int NUM_VERTICES = 1024;
const int NUM_EDGES = 1024;

int vertices[NUM_VERTICES];
    Edge edges[NUM_EDGES];
    int first, second;

FILE *infile;
char *path = "DataSet/1024.txt";
char line[100];

infile = fopen(path, "r");

if (!infile) {
    printf("Couldn't open %s for reading\n", path);
    exit(-1);
}
int i=0;
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), infile)!= NULL) 
{

    sscanf(line, "%d\t%d", first, second);

    edges[i].first = first;
    edges[i].second = second;
    i++;
}

fclose(infile);
printf("Data Set:\n\n");


for (int i = 0; i < NUM_EDGES; ++i)
{
    printf("%d -> %d", edges[i].first, edges[i].second);
    printf(((i % 4) != 3) ? "\t":"\n");
}
```

When I run the code I get a

```
Segmentation fault: 11
```

What am I doing wrong here.

Comment: Why don't you show the full file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
sscanf(line, "%d\t%d", &first, &second);
```

Note the `&`s. They make a pointer holding the addresses for `first` and `second`. That is required since they need to be modified by `sscanf()` and they can be through these pointers.

The way it was, your program invoked *Undefined Behavior* since, you passed uninitialized integers that were considered addresses by `sscanf()`, trying to dereference them in order to store the result in `first` and `second` was causing the mentioned *undefined behavior* leading to the segmentation fault.

There is another risk in your code. If you ignore the value returned by `sscanf()` and yet you try to read from `first` or `second`, there is another chance for undefined behavior. Read [`scanf(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) for more information.  Better would be:

```
int n;
...
n = sscanf(line, "%d\t%d", &first, &second);
if (n != 2) { /* do something appropriate here */ }
```

Finally, you would know all this if you turn on compilation warnings, it's hard to tell you how to do it since, every compiler and/or IDE are different but just google it for your particular situation and you will find warnings very helpful.  For example, using gcc on a unix system:

```
% pr -t -n xx.c
    1   #include <stdio.h>
    2   
    3   int main ( void ) {
    4           char line[100];
    5           int     first, second;
    6   
    7           (void)fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    8           (void)sscanf(line, "%d\t%d", first, second);
    9           return 0;
   10   }
   11   
% cc -c xx.c
% cc -c -Wall xx.c
xx.c: In function `main':
xx.c:8: warning: format argument is not a pointer (arg 3)
xx.c:8: warning: format argument is not a pointer (arg 4)
```

Note how the first compile (`cc -c xx.c`) was less helpful than the second (`cc -c -Wall xx.c`) where we asked for "all" warnings.

Comment: When you give an answer, better explain it. Don't give fish teach how to fish instead.

Comment: FYI, I was looking for a previous SO Q&A for the longer explanation as I'm sure this has been asked and answered a jillion times...

Comment: @John I don't understand why these people don't even bother to look at the error messages from the compiler.

Comment: @JohnHascall Then don't answer it until you make sure.

Comment: @smlq They probably don't understand the error. And also, they probably don't know that they can use a debugger, which would have let them know where the error was happening. On the other hand, if you mean that the compiler didn't warn about the way `sscanf()` was called, it might be the case where the compiler is invoked without warnings enabled.

Comment: @JohnHascall Very nice to worry about style, though in my opinion (please don't respond to this comment) it's nicer to use more meaningful variable names or `if (sscanf(line, "%d%d", &first, &second) != 2)` which is even better. Also, note that the `\t` is not needed since `"%d"` stops at the first white space character it finds anyway and ignore leading ones.